# PHP Unit testing dispatched events

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

How does one test that events were dispatched during a function call?

```
public function updateUser() {
    //Do some update stuff

    $event = new UserUpdated($user);

    $event->attach([
        new SendEmailAddressChangeEmail($emailAddress),
        new SendEmailAddressChangeEmail($oldEmailAddress),
    ]);
    $event->dispatch();
}
```

Aside from setting up an email address and seeing if an email is sent, how can I check (using PHP Unit) that the dispatcher is actually dispatching these events? I am assuming that I need to create a mock of some sort, but I am uncertain how to create a mock for a completely unrelated bit of code.

UserUpdated Event code:

```
class UserUpdated extends BaseEvent
{

    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

and the related SendEmailAddressChanged Handler code:

```
class SendEmailAddressChangeEmail implements Contracts\HandlerInterface
{
    protected $emailAddress;

    public function __construct($emailAddress) {
        $this->emailAddress = $emailAddress;
    }

    public function handle($event) {
        EmailUtils::sendEmailAddressChangeEmail($this->emailAddress, $event->user->userName, $event->user->userID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `updateUser()` method you've got does two things in one that especially does not work well with (unit) testing:

1. business logic
2. object creation

From your own sense of things I assume this is also what made you ask this question. Often code that is not straight forward to test also is a good canary for design issues, so it is normally best to tackle w/ it.

> These two points (1. and 2.) are an over-simplification of what is borrowed from the "Two piles" outlined by Misko Hevery in far more detail in his *Clean Code Talks*:
>
> [image]
>
> For example in "The Clean Code Talks -- Inheritance, Polymorphism, & Testing" from Nov 2008 - https://youtu.be/4F72VULWFvc?t=1328 ("Two Piles" @ 22:08)

One solution to make this code more test-able is the use of *dependency injection*. That is one factory (method) for the user-event and one factory  (method) for the object `updateUser()` is a method of. That concrete type then can make use of the factory object it gets injected to obtain the even object.

In short: If that update-user object needs a user-updated-event object it needs to ask for it in it's constructor.

As you sometimes don't want to create that user-updated-event object beforehand, the alternative is inject an object that knows how to create that user-updated-event object, these kind of objects are called *factories*.

The test then can inject a factory that presents an event mock object with the expectation that it is dispatched.

A good dispatch library btw. does already provide ready-made mocks for tests but that is out of the scope of Phpunit.

If you don't know yet about the mock functionality of Phpunit, please checkout the product's documentation for it:

- [Phpunit 7.1 Docs » 9. Test Doubles](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.1/test-doubles.html)

Comment: This is exactly the type of response I was hoping for. I had a feeling that the issue went deeper than just testing, but I couldn't quite put my finger on it. Thank you for the in depth response! I'll look into refactoring the code.